# Configure BDC, SSP to access external data error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have configured BDC and SSP to get access to external data, but get this error when trying to create External Content Type:  Message from External System: 'Cannot logon with credentials from Secure Store Provider'.  Using Impersonated Windows Identity.  Any thoughts on what the issue is?

Comment: What is the source of your external data?

Comment: A SQL 2008 database.